# Are any social media sites sanitizing images?

Tags: malware, steganography, image, social-media

I'm new to steganography. I have some questions about images on social media sites.

I saw that Facebook [recently patched a vulnerability](https://blog.checkpoint.com/2020/09/24/instahack-how-researchers-were-able-to-take-over-the-instagram-app-using-a-malicious-image/) on Instagram, but I was wondering whether any of the major sites (Facebook, Twitter, SnapChat) sanitize images? I assume not, but want to cover my bases.

Comment: If you are worried about malware, note that the images uploaded are most often compressed, which would remove and embedded code. It might not remove all forms of steganographic messages, but it would remove binary data.

Comment: That vulnerability would not have been fixed with "sanitation". By the way, what do you mean by "sanitation"? What do you think that would do?

Comment: From what little I understand, images can be scanned for malware, but this is usually only for email attachments. I've heard the term sanitizing, where malware or questionable data in the image is removed, but leaves the image itself in tact.

Comment: You would first have to know what's image and what's not. That's not a normal or typical thing to be able to do when you don't have a reference image. You can strip metadata, but how do you determine if a byte of an image results in an image part or is part of something else?